# how to add custom routes to refinerycms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, refinery

i need to add a custom path to refinerycms project, here is how i did it:

```
mount Refinery::Core::Engine, :at => '/'
get 'news/more' => 'refinery::news::items#view_more', as: :news_view_more
```

now 'rake routes' can prints correct routes, but i can't refer to that path by refinery.news_view_more_path, however i found some code like ’refinery.news_item_path‘ in refinerycms gem source code, i want my custom routes can be refered that way.

thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@manosagent, i can add routes like that:

```
Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.prepend do
  get 'news/more' => 'news::items#view_more', as: :news_view_more
  get 'notices/more' => 'notices::notices#view_more', as: :notices_view_more
end
```

but i don't understand why `new/more` appears twice in `rake routes`, i need to dig deeper ...

Answer (score 0):

I believe since your routing is not RESTFUL you will not be able to use helpers to get the paths you want. You should either use RESTFUL routing or create a helper for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent some time to figure it out. If you are using separate controller in your rails app, then you can put your routes code on top of the routes. Remember that routes wont work on refinery page `view/refinery/*.*`. If you want to add some custom routes on refinery page like `view/refinery/*.*` then you can follow below code.

```
Refinery::Core::Engine.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  get 'author' => 'author#index'
end
```

on your routes file.

Answer (score 0):

Refinery CMS deeply hacked its routes, there are plenty patches from "refinery gems", so that all the urls will be filtered by Refinery's Core Action(such as Refinery::PagesController#show )

Actually I don't have time to dive in, all above is my guess...

So if you want to add a new route, just add non-RESTful route there, e.g.:

```
get 'news/more' => 'refinery::news::items#view_more', as: :news_view_more
```

put this line before refinery's other routes, will work.